# Get local time in seconds using Qt

Tags: qt, utc, localtime, qdatetime

I am stuck with this problem.

I already got the `currentUTCtime` in seconds from the `QDateTime`. 
Problem is, I can't find a possible way to convert this into the local time in seconds. There are some QDate functions like `toLocalTime()` which just don't seem to work. I hope somebody here can help me.

```
QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
QDateTime currentateTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QDateTime UTC(QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc());
currentDateTime.toString().toStdString();
TimeNow = currentDateTime.toMSecsSinceEpoch()/1000;
```

Above is my code for the currentUTC Time in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the time in seconds since the epoch you can use `QDateTime::toTime_t()`; this method exists in Qt 4.7 and seems to be a part of Qt 5 from the start, too.

```
QDateTime::currentDateTime().toTime_t()
```

for local time, or for UTC

```
QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc().toTime_t()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [QDateTime::fromTime_t](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromTime_t-1), to which the documentation states:

> Returns a datetime whose date and time are the number of seconds that have passed since 1970-01-01T00:00:00, Coordinated Universal Time (Qt::UTC) and *converted to the given spec*.

```
qint64 utcTime = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
QDateTime localTime = QDateTime::fromTime_t(utcTime, Qt::LocalTime);
```

Comment: ah thats a nice one. Thank you! the Problem now is that there is an error saying : no matching function for call to 'QDateTime::fromTime_t(qint64&, Qt::TimeSpec)' am i missing something?

Comment: You must be using at least Qt 5.2

Comment: Oh that is going to be the problem. Which is just not realizeable at this point. could there be any other way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Qt 4.8 has [QDateTime::toTimeSpec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#toTimeSpec) which may be of use.